# if $x^2 - x^4 > 0$, which is greater, x or 1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For some reason, I can guess the answer to this, but I don't have a mathematical reasoning solution that I can live with. I get this far:

1. $x^2 - x^4 > 0$
2. $x^2 > x^4$

but the leap, that seems needed is to:

3. $1 > x^2$

and:

4. $1 > x$

Which answers the question that 1 is larger than x.

How do I move from (2) to (3) and (4)?

Comment: 2 to 3 sounds trivial? divide by x^2 on both ends and the inequality still holds

Comment: You missed a step:$$\sqrt1>\sqrt{x^2}=|x|\ne x$$Not that it really affects the problem.

Comment: and for 3 to 4, $1-x^2>0$, this is a quadratic inequality which could be solved by inspection or by analysis of its derivative

Comment: I think the OP isn't in Calculus yet. Instead, a polynomial inequality (as well as many other types of inequalities) can be solved by finding the roots first and then examining intervals on the number line with the help of "test points".

Comment: how do I unask? With gebra's observation and Simply Beautiful Art's comment the question is answered. Ziprovich is correct, I am not yet using Calculus.

Comment: You don't need to delete the question, I think it is reasonably good.

Comment: You can leap from 2 to 3 by a) noting x doesn't equal 0, b) $x^2 > 0$ so therefore $x^2/x^2 > x^4/x^2$.  But you do need to do a) and b) (although they are simple and ... "obvious").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(3) Simply divide each side by $x^2$ to get $1>x^2$

For this, you have already stated that $x^2 < 1$ Therefore, if $x$ is negative, it wouldn't satisfy the inequality.

(4) Square root both sides to obtain $1>x$

Comment: That is if $x>0$

Comment: Okay, I overlooked that @dydxx I will edit it ASAP

Comment: ok, so $1 > x^2, 1 > |x|, -1 < x <  1$ the question is answered.

Answer (score 2):

An idea: for $\;x\neq0\;$

$$0<x^2-x^4=x^2(1-x^2)\;.$$

Since $\;x^2>0\;$ , we **must have**

$$1-x^2>0\implies x^2<1\implies|x|<1\iff -1 <x<1\,,\,\,x\neq0$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x\ge1$; then also $x^2\ge1$ and, being $x^2>0$, also $x^4\ge x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that $x^2-x^4>0$. Then, we have to observe that $x\neq 0$ and so, $x^2>0$ so that $\frac{1}{x^2}>0$. Thus,
$$\begin{align}
x^2-x^4>0&\implies x^2(1-x^2)>0\\
&\implies \frac{1}{x^2}x^2(1-x^2)>0\frac{1}{x^2}\\
&\implies 1-x^2>0\\
&\implies x^2<1\\
&\implies \sqrt{x^2}<\sqrt{1}\\
&\implies |x|<1\\
&\implies -1<x<1\\
\end{align}
$$
The answer to your question is $1>x$.

Comment: This makes sense, and was sort of how my intuition went, as well. If I could accept both answers, I would, but the other one seems more straightforward - read easier.

Comment: @decuser No problem to me. Just want to share my thoughts.

Comment: @decuser You certainly can accept (green checkmark) only one answer, but you can **upvote** as many as you want. If you liked this answer then it deserves your upvote, eventhough you already accepted other answer.